# Is there a way for different flex swf's to send large blocks of data between each other without localconnection?

Tags: apache-flex, localconnection

Is there a way for different flex swf's to send large blocks of data between each other without using localconnection which is size limited or using sharedobjects.  This needs to happen on the client without server communication.

Answer (score 0):

How large are we talking about?  Any client side solutions is limited by size for security purposes.  You either use LocalConnection, SharedObjects or Javascript.

If it's too big, you might want to split up the object in chunks and send it over piece by piece.  I've done this myself with LocalConnection and streaming data. Other than that, you could always have it done using user interactions (save a file, browse the file in the other Flex swf).  Why are there 2 Flex swfs anyways?  And why do they need to communicate large amounts of data between the two?

Answer (score 0):

If the two swf's are both running in the same web page then you should be able to use the ExternalInterface classes with some JavaScript to forward the data from one swf to the other as there is no limit (I believe) on ExternalInterface calls.

Other than that your only choices are to use the LocalConnection or SharedObject methods. I have also had success with splitting large data into smaller chunks and used the local connection classes to send it piece by piece, if you do this then just watch out because each block of data sent will not necessarily be received in the order in which it was sent!

Comment: I went with externalinterface. I found lc to limiting.